# unable to install madwifi

Tags: internet, madwifi

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 last night after completely formatting the HDD. Now, I can't get any wifi or ethernet connection. I have downloaded madwifi on another computer and transfered it over to my laptop but when I try and install it, I get an error that says "Unable to find package" I can't update anything or use Synaptic package manager. Any help is appreciated. The laptop is a Toshiba Satellite L50-A

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you please explain some more how and where you downloaded madwifi and how you tried to install it. Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/382227/edit) and add the information.

Answer (score 0):

Madwifi can be installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install collectd-core collectd-dev collectd-dbg collectd-utils
```